# How to write data to firestore through firebase functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I can quite easily find how to add triggers for firestore events but I can't find any documentation on how to use firebase functions to write to firestore.

For example I have the following:

```
export const listener = functions.auth.user().onCreate((x)=>{
    //firestore function to add an entry for user with fields...
})
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this? Is it that the logic for adding data to firestore should be written client side? If so wouldn't that mean I would need to re-write that functionality for every platform?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to read and write Firestore in the same way you'd use it to read and write Realtime Database.  There are plenty of [official examples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/), especially [this quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore).

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original}).then(writeResult => {
    // write is complete here
});
```

Comment: Hi Doug, I would like to know if its possible to write the above in firebase cloud function and connect it to the front-end.
What I mean is writing and storing all firebase api calls in the cloud function

Comment: Is it possible to check the existing data first so as to not add copies in the database?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who ends up here, the quickstart link mentioned in @doug-stevenson 's comment has been updated to a new endpoint,its now [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore)